# Realtime text display issue in terminal

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, display

I want to display text in my terminal as my script executes. However, when I use the "**echo**" command within a method created in my script, the text doesn't appear instantly, but only once the method is finished executing.

Exemple of method:

```
get_src_port() {
port=10000
echo "use default port ?" # This is not display 
gum choose "$YES" "$NO"
if [ "$answer" = "no" ]; then
  port=$(gum input --placeholder "Enter the port and press [ENTER]: ")  # This is display 
fi
echo $port # This is not display 
}
```

How I call my method :

```
src_port=$(get_src_port)
```

Only the '**gum**' instructions appear gradually as the script runs.

Comment: Cannot reproduce; sorry. Anyway, your `answer` never gets a value, so your `if` condition will always be false. Oh, and please remove the marketing paragraph for `gum`; it has no value in your question.

Comment: You did not show how you invoke `get_src_port`. It could be that `gum` writes directly to the terminal, while `get_src_port` is run in a context where stdout has been redirected. So please clarify this first.

Comment: @user1934428 like this ``` src_port=$(get_src_port) ```

Comment: That's what I meant: You are grabbing the stdout from your function, but `gum` is not writing to stdout, so you can see its output, but you can't see your `echo`. Please update your question with the way you call the function, as this is crucial to understand your problem.

Comment: thank you I do this, is there a way to do like gum?